# variable passing inside a function to another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables

```
setTimeout("refresh()", 2*15000);
```

This is a code from my JavaScript.

Here setTimeout is a built in function and refresh is a function which I have declared.

I want to pass a variable (cval1) to this refresh function.

I have tried this:

```
setTimeout("refresh(cval1)", 2*15000 );
```

But it's not working.

What is the exact way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As first parameter of setTimeout pass a function instead of a string, so you have access to all variables in current scope.

```
setTimeout(function(){refresh(cval1)}, 2*15000);
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading an article regarding javascript timers and scope.  Here's a tutorial I found with a quick Google search - http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-using-setinterval-and-settimeout